# GeneXus 16 .NET U10 - Import OpenAPI - OpenAPI 3.0.0 supported?

Tags: genexus

I am importing a OpenAPI 3.0.0 yaml file in to GX 16 U10 and am getting the following error:

```
========== OpenAPI Import started ==========
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from C:/test.yaml
[main] INFO io.swagger.parser.Swagger20Parser - reading from C:/test.yaml
[main] ERROR io.swagger.parser.SwaggerCompatConverter - failed to read resource listing
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'openapi': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
...
error: Error trying to read data from file path or url
Failed: OpenAPI Import
```

From the top of the error, it looks like this is trying to use swagger 2.0.  Is OpenAPI 3.0 supported?  Is there a work around?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately OpenAPI 3.0 is not currently (GX16u10) supported.
It is on GeneXus' backlog, so hopefully you'll see it soon.

Comment: Hi Sebastian.  Hope all is well with you all.  Do you know of another way of doing this in the meantime?  I saw on the swagger editor (where I opened the 3.0 version) I could convert it to JSON.  I then used the Import JSON in U10 over this file (Microsoft Navision ERP API) and it did create one HUGE SDT.  From your perspective, do you think this will work?

Comment: Hello Scott, I realize my answer got cut off... anyways, I think taking it to Json is a good option. Let us know how it works.